# Create Wifi Ad-hoc to connect Ubuntu and windows 8.1

Tags: wireless, server, windows-8, connection

I want to build a wifi Ad-Hoc in my Ubuntu that my friend with windows 8.1 can connect to it. is it possible. please clarify me what should i do.tnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am a complete noob, but here is something that you can at least try...
I am using 14.04 LTS, so it might be a slightly different process for you. Note: you must either be connected to Ethernet or have a usb wifi adapter for this to work.

First, click on the top right where all of your wifi networks are listed. Then, near the bottom of that list click "Edit wifi networks." This will open a page with the networks that you have most recently used on the front. Click the add button on the top right, and when it asks you for the connection type, make sure to click "wifi." Then, set the connection name and SSID to whatever you want, provided that the SSID is one word. Also, change the mode from Infrastructure to Ad Hoc. If you want your hotspot to be password protected, then move over to the security tab and select WEP 128-bit passphrase from the dropdown list. Lastly, move over to the IPv4 settings and select "shared to other computers" near the bottom of the dropdown list. Click save on the bottom right.

Next, click on the wifi list again from the top right of your screen. Click on add a new wifi network near the bottom. On the dropdown menu select the name of whatever you named your hotspot. It will autofill all of the information. Then click "Ok." Now, your computer will automatically connect to the hotspot, and it should be visible to those relatively near you. However, it won't actually work yet because your computer isn't actually connected to your router. This is why you need to plug into Ethernet or plug in a separate USB wifi adapter and connect to our home network from there. Then, it should work. Good Luck!